# What does it mean in the changelog of msysgit 1.7.11 when it says: An experimental "version 4" format of the index file

Tags: git, msysgit

As stated in the title,

what do they mean:

> An experimental "version 4" format of the index file has been introduced to reduce on-disk footprint and I/O overhead

More importantly, is there a risk in losing backwards compatibility with this change, or could this change corrupt the repository?

Doing some testing suggests that it's backwards compatible and did not reveal any adverse effects.

Could somebody please clarify what this change actually is to msysgit 1.7.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue of compatibility here (between msysgit and git, or with previous revision of Git), as this is the same modification than in git repo itself (and the official Git repo doesn't mention any compatibility issue).

See, in the [*git* repo](https://github.com/git/git) the file [`Documentation/technical/index-format.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt) about the GIT index format:

> (Version 4) In version 4, the entry path name is prefix-compressed
> relative to the path name for the previous entry (the very first
> entry is encoded as if the path name for the previous entry is an
> empty string).
> At the beginning of an entry, an integer `N` in the
> variable width encoding (the same encoding as the offset is encoded
> for `OFS_DELTA` pack entries; see [pack-format.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt)) is stored, followed
> by a NUL-terminated string `S`.
> Removing `N` bytes from the end of the path name for the previous entry, and replacing it with the string `S` yields the path name for this entry.
>
> 1-8 nul bytes as necessary to pad the entry to a multiple of eight bytes while keeping the name NUL-terminated.
>
> (Version 4) In version 4, the padding after the pathname does not
> exist.

So this is really *internal* management of the *index* entry, which doesn't prevent a git (1.7.11 or any other version) to clone / read a remote repo.
It aims only to optimize the "entry path name" representation.

---

> I wonder that what does it mean "1-8 nul bytes"?, can null terminated be 1-byte up to 8 byte ?

The null terminator of a string is always a single byte (`\0`). The "1-8 nul bytes" refers specifically to padding bytes added after the null terminator for alignment purposes, not to the null terminator itself. In Version 4 of the index format, this specific type of padding after pathnames has been removed to optimize storage.

In the context of the Git index file, entries are padded with null bytes (`\0`) to align them to a multiple of eight bytes. That alignment is important for making sure that the data structure is optimized for access and manipulation, improving performance on many systems. The specification mentions "1-8 nul bytes" because the exact number of null bytes added depends on the length of the entry. The goal is to make the total size of the entry (including its path name, and other metadata) a multiple of eight bytes.

- **Null-Terminated String**: A null-terminated string is a sequence of characters followed by a null byte (`\0`) that signals the end of the string. That is a standard way to represent strings in C and many other programming environments. In this context, the null terminator is always one byte.
- **1-8 Nul Bytes for Padding**: After the null terminator that indicates the end of the string, additional null bytes may be added as padding. The "1-8 nul bytes" phrase means that after the string's null terminator, enough null bytes are added to make sure the total size of the entry is aligned to an 8-byte boundary. The number of padding bytes required can vary from one (if the entry is already seven bytes away from being a multiple of eight) to eight (if the entry size is already a multiple of eight, and thus an entire new block of eight bytes will be used for padding to maintain alignment).
- **Why Padding Does Not Exist in Version 4 for the Pathname**: The documentation note that in Version 4 of the index file format, the padding after the pathname does not exist, is highlighting an optimization. Unlike previous versions, Version 4 optimizes storage by eliminating unnecessary padding bytes after the pathname, which was used to make sure alignment. That change is part of the overall effort to reduce disk space usage and improve efficiency.

Comment: I know, this is very old topic, but I wonder that what does it mean "1-8 nul bytes"?, can null terminated be 1-byte up to 8 byte ? @VonC